# How to pass angularjs $upload in controller

Tags: angularjs

For File uploading in Angularjs **$upload** is injecting into controller(RegistrationCtrl), But there are multiple scope, $location etc are injected into it. Then while injecting $upload into the RegistraionCtrl I am getting some injector errors in console and page is not loading properly.

**Controller** **Code as follows:**

```
.controller("registrationCtrl",["$scope","$rootScope","$upload","$location","logger","$http","$q","$modal","$log",function($scope,$rootScope,$upload,$location,logger,$http,$q,$modal,$log){

});
```

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15-build.2399+sha.ca4ddfa/$injector/unpr?p0=%24uploadProvider%20%3C-%20%24upload

Comment: I'm not aware of any service named `$upload` in angular core. If that is in an external module then make sure you have included that script in your HTML. Also make sure you've declared a depenedency on it while initializing your module.

Comment: i got similar kind of problem while injecting the service layer into the controller with logger service, then i solved it specifying the logger before to the service injection  into controller            Example .controller("registrationCtrl",["$scope","$rootScope","$upload","$location","logger","regService",function($scope,$rootScope,$upload,$location,logger,regService){

});